# Handling errors in react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

According to documentation of react-hook-form I can use name of input element like this "xxx.yyy" and this will result in my prepared data to be

```
{ xxx: { yyy: value }}
```

But when I try to use this feature with 'errors' I cannot use it. i.e. I cannot write below:

```
{errors.xxx.yyy && <span>This field is required</span>}
```

because I get "Cannot read property 'yyy' of undefined".

[Documentation](https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage) says that I should use this chaining operator, ?. , so I try it:

```
{errors?.xxx?.yyy && <span>This field is required</span>}
```

But nothing displays on the page if required input is omitted. I can see that the mechanism blocks form from being submitted until I write something in this field, that is OK, but why I don't get the error message on the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it really depend which version you are using.

V3: flat error object

```
errors['xxx.yyyy']
```

V4: Nested errors object with better type support

```
errors?.xxx?.yyyy
```

we have also build a `ErrorMessage` component which you may find it useful.

https://react-hook-form.com/api#ErrorMessage

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found answer myself. I should use this form:

{errors['xxx.yyy'] && This field is required}

Then everything works :-)

Answer (score 1):

you don't want to spend your coding time. you can use `@hookform/error-message` instead of code manually. it's very easy. it'll manage those errors.
just pass the errors object given by react-hook-form and pass the property name that you want to display the error message.

```
<ErrorMessage errors={errors} name="xxx.yyy" message="This is required" />
```

OR

if you want to customize your message as you want, you can `render` as you want like below.
think that you want to bold and show invalid with red custom css class. then you can render as you want.

```
<ErrorMessage render={({message}) => <div className="invalid-feedback d-block"><b> {message} </b></div>} errors={errors} name="xxx.yyy"/>
```

NPM https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hookform/error-message